# Exporting time series of multiple polygons to .csv without using ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion command

Tags: google-earth-engine

Following the example provided in the GE tutorial  (see below), how can I export the data to a .csv without using the `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion`?

```js
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'})
]);

// Load Landsat 8 brightness temperature data for 1 year.
var temps2013 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_TOA')
    .filterDate('2012-12-25', '2013-12-25')
    .select('B11');

// Create a time series chart.
var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    temps2013, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'B11', 200, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Temperature over time in regions of the American West',
          vAxis: {title: 'Temperature (Kelvin)'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
          series: {
            0: {color: 'FF0000'}, // urban
            1: {color: '00FF00'}, // forest
            2: {color: '0000FF'}  // desert
}});

// Display.
print(tempTimeSeries);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions generally need more than code, and they need to be formatted to be legible -- Use the `{}` button to indent four spaces for code. Please indicate what you have tried within the question.

Comment: This is what I tried: 
var TempsOverTimeByRegion = reduceRegions({
  imageCollection: temps2013,
  regions: westernRegions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  band: 'Temp',
  scale: 200,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'label'
});

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include the code instead of posting it to the comments.

Answer (score 4):

It's going to be something like this (from [this reference](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1D7rezUHPElCfYWHMRNBChHjbEv6nXDD8xnh7_YgyK6A/edit#slide=id.g21c09d71c4_0_0) on [this page](https://events.withgoogle.com/google-earth-engine-user-summit-2017/breakout-sessions/#content))

```js
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'})
]);

// Load Landsat 8 brightness temperature data for 1 year.
var temps2013 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_TOA')
    .filterDate('2012-12-25', '2013-12-25')
    .select('B11');

// Collect region, image, value triplets.
var triplets = temps2013.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('B11').reduceRegions({
    collection: regions.select(['label']), 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 30
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', image.id());
    });
}).flatten();
print(triplets.first());

// Format a table of triplets into a 2D table of rowId x colId.
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  // Get a FeatureCollection with unique row IDs.
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId);
  // Join the table to the unique IDs to get a collection in which
  // each feature stores a list of all features having a common row ID. 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });

  return joined.map(function(row) {
      // Get the list of all features with a unique row ID.
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        // Map a function over the list of rows to return a list of
        // column ID and value.
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('mean')];
        });
      // Return the row with its ID property and properties for
      // all matching columns IDs storing the output of the reducer.
      // The Dictionary constructor is using a list of key, value pairs.
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};

var link = '6430802a354ca3e5d5267718173afac7';

var table1 = format(triplets, 'imageId', 'label');

var desc1 = 'table_demo_' + link; 
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table1, 
  description: desc1, 
  fileNamePrefix: desc1,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Watch out for those 32-day composites.  They may be full of clouds.

Comment: Using `feature.get('mean')` in `format` confused me.  I guess it is taking the mean of the mean value in `triplets`?