# Google Earth Engine : Get "table" and not a Chart, of time series multiple polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, time-series

Based on the example mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254138/exporting-time-series-of-multiple-polygons-to-csv-without-using-ui-chart-image), and based on the answer provided below,

```
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'})
]);

// Load Landsat 8 brightness temperature data for 1 year.
var temps2013 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_TOA')
    .filterDate('2012-12-25', '2013-12-25')
    .select('B11');

// Collect region, image, value triplets.
var triplets = temps2013.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('B11').reduceRegions({
    collection: regions.select(['label']), 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 30
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', image.id());
    });
}).flatten();
print(triplets.first());

// Format a table of triplets into a 2D table of rowId x colId.
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  // Get a FeatureCollection with unique row IDs.
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId);
  // Join the table to the unique IDs to get a collection in which
  // each feature stores a list of all features having a common row ID. 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });

  return joined.map(function(row) {
      // Get the list of all features with a unique row ID.
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        // Map a function over the list of rows to return a list of
        // column ID and value.
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('mean')];
        });
      // Return the row with its ID property and properties for
      // all matching columns IDs storing the output of the reducer.
      // The Dictionary constructor is using a list of key, value pairs.
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};

var link = '6430802a354ca3e5d5267718173afac7';

var table1 = format(triplets, 'imageId', 'label');

var desc1 = 'table_demo_' + link; 
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table1, 
  description: desc1, 
  fileNamePrefix: desc1,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

is there no simpler way to get a table of a time series from multiple polygons?
But I don't know, I find it bizarre that there is no simple way to get a table, as this example below where ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion could be replace by a specific function ?

```
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'})
]);



var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1');
var modisLST = modis.filterBounds(regions)
                    .filterDate('2003-12-25', '2004-02-25')
                    .select('LST_Day_1km');

// Convert temperature to Celsius.
modisLST = modisLST.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15).copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
});

// Create a graph of the time-series.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: modisLST, 
  regions: fc2, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
})
print(graph)
```

I'm working on thousands of points and try to avoid the Chart output 5 and it's even not working since out of limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion` function actually wraps some reduction computations and then does the plotting for you, which is very nice for exploring and creating quick charts but doesn't give you the data in a variable you can use. You can simulate that functionality with you own function to extract the time series for your featureCollection and have a list of arrays. Here is an example:

```
// Define a FeatureCollection: regions of the American West.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // San Francisco.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Tahoe National Forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-121, 39.4, -120.8, 39.8), {label: 'Forest'}),
  ee.Feature(  // Black Rock Desert.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-119.15, 40.8, -119, 41), {label: 'Desert'})
]);


var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1');
var modisLST = modis.filterBounds(regions)
                    .filterDate('2003-12-25', '2004-02-25')
                    .select('LST_Day_1km');

// Convert temperature to Celsius.
modisLST = modisLST.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15).copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});              


function imageCollection_to_timeSeries(imageCollection,featureCollection,reducer,scale){
  var noDataValue = -999; // internal no data value to use

  // loop over all of the images in the collection
  var series = modisLST.map(function(img){
    var t = ee.List([img.date().millis()]); // get time information
    var fc = img.reduceRegions(regions,reducer,scale); // get the mean values
    // loop over the results and check if the value is non null
    fc = fc.map(function(feature){
      var v = ee.List(feature.get('mean'));
      // set no data if value is null
      var setter = ee.Algorithms.If(v,v,noDataValue);
      return feature.set('result',setter);
    });
    // get a list of the results
    var results = ee.List(fc.aggregate_array('result'));
    // return a feature with time and reduction values for each feature
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(0,0),{'values':results,'time':t});
  });

  // extract some information to format the time series arrays
  var keys = ee.List.sequence(0,featureCollection.size().subtract(1));
  var x = ee.Array(series.aggregate_array('time'));
  var y = ee.Array(series.aggregate_array('values'));

  // loop over all of the features
  var df = keys.map(function(i){
    i = ee.Number(i);
    // slice out time series for feature
    var v = y.slice(1,i,i.add(1));
    // create mask for array
    var mask = v.neq(noDataValue);
    // return dictionary with time index and values
    return ee.List([ee.Dictionary({'index':x.mask(mask),'values':v.mask(mask)})]);
  }).flatten();

  return df;
}

// call custom function
var df = imageCollection_to_timeSeries(modisLST,regions,ee.Reducer.mean(),1000);

// do whatever is needed with the individual arrays after this
print(df);

// get time series for first feature
var x1 = ee.Dictionary(df.get(0)).get('index');
var y1 = ee.Dictionary(df.get(0)).get('values');

// and create a chart from the array
var arrayChart = ui.Chart.array.values(y1,0,x1).setChartType('LineChart');
print('Chart from array',arrayChart);

// Create a graph of the time-series using the default ee.ui.chart functionality.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: modisLST, 
  regions: regions, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
});
print('Default ee.ui.Chart',graph);
```

This a little bit of a work around to handle different no data information and different length arrays for different features but you will essentially have all of the array information you need and can extract/manipulate how you want for further processing. Here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/69689134d4449dcb984a0db34f35ed96). I hope this helps!